# WriteFile() Function for Win32 Applications

Tags: c++, winapi

I am facing a problem on the WriteFile(); function using Win32 C++ Application.  the second argument asks for a pointer to the buffer that is storing the information. what Syntax do I use to point the input text from the boxes? My information is text from the input of text boxes. What syntax do i use to create a pointer to that?

Here is a snippet of code the code I am using:

```
case IDC_BUTTON_ONE:
                   {
                      HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("C:\\test.txt", GENERIC_READ,
                      0, NULL, CREATE_NEW, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
                   }
```

Comment: The text is in a string - an array of char. Assuming you are using an actual array of char or a class that will act as a simple array, you pass the array as the buffer.

Comment: When you can't figure out how to use an API function, the very first stop should be to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com). The [docs for WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) includes a link to an [example of opening a file for reading and writing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that shows how to allocate, fill, and pass the buffer.

Comment: Not for the buffer option, I have been using MSDN to aid in my programming, but the second argument to WriteFile(); is just a paragraph stating to make a pointer to the buffer with the information contained therein. That is why i asked here.

Comment: The reason that you can't just point to a textbox buffer is because there's no guarantee how the text is exactly stored by that textbox. In particular, you seem to use non-Unicode functions while the textbox internally will probably be Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

To write a control's text to a file you'll also need these lines:

```
char TextBuffer[256]; // Ascii
GetDlgItemTextA(hDlg, IDC_YOUR_CONTROL_ID, TextBuffer, ARRAY_SIZE(TextBuffer));
WriteFile(hFile, TextBuffer, strlen(TextBuffer), &SizeOut, lpOverlapped);
```

That'll just write plain old ASCII. If you want to use `unicode` and `TCHAR`s (instead of chars) then you'll need to choose your encoding and write more than "just the bytes" from the text buffer.

Comment: `GetDlgItemText()` returns how many characters were actually written to the array. Use that value instead of `strlen()`.